# How do I debug Javascript in an AngularJS partial?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, angularjs-routing

I am using the `Routing and Multiple Views` feature of AngularJS but I don't see the HTML partial file (or the embedded Javascript) in Chrome's "Sources" tab of the Developer Tools.

In my index.html file, it includes all the  tags for AngularJS, jQuery and Bootstrap along with my custom app/controller Javascript file.  These files all appear in the Sources tab.

My application works correctly.  As I click around between the links on the page, the partial HTML files are loaded and displayed and the files are listed in the Network tab.

The problem is that the partial HTML files do not appear in the Sources tab.  How can I debug the Javascript in those partial files?

Comment: Why do you have javascript in your partials?

Comment: Why not?  If I have code that only applies to the HTML in that partial, why not leave it there?  (Apart from this problem in viewing the code in the Source tab, that is.)  My goal is to have the HTML and related code in the same file.

Comment: Any code related to your DOM should go in a directive in the `link` option. Generally, logic within your view is a bad design paradigm as the 2 become coupled, not to mention hard to test

Comment: Ignoring the paradigms for now, is there a way to debug Javascript in AngularJS partial HTML files?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the closest thing to a debugger is [Zone.js](https://github.com/btford/zone.js/) from the Angular team, especially since it [will be built right into AngularJS in the future](http://thechangelog.com/zone-js/).

This means adding some more code, but the benefits seem to outweigh the cost.